Creating word document with photos and descriptions with VBA
I am trying to create a word document report that includes photos with an associated description using Excel VBA.  The photo names are in column A and the descriptions are in columns B:I of the excel spreadsheet.  The current macro opens the FileDialogFolderPicker and the user pick the folder that contains the pictures they want.  The macro picks the associated picture based off the photo name in coulmn A then creates the word document and inserts the photos and descriptions. I am having trouble with inserting the correct photos and descriptions into the word document in the correct locations.  I would also like to lock the aspect ratio of each photo and be able to specify the size of the photo in inches.  I have included photos of what is currently happening with the word document and also what I would like the final result to look like.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sub Module2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngPict As Range, rngP As Range, cel As Range
    Dim myDialog As FileDialog, myFolder As String, myFile As String, myPicture As String
    Dim x As Single, y As Single, W As Single, h As Single
    Const picturesColumn As String = "A" 'the column keeping the pictures name list
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 
    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, picturesColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'last row for photo names
    Set rngPict = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, picturesColumn), ws.Cells(lastR, picturesColumn)) 'the photo names range
    
    Set myDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With myDialog
       .Title = "Select the folder with structure photos"
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'nothing has been selected...
       myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        .Documents.Add
    
    End With
    
    'Iterate between each cell of pictures range and insert if picture exists in myFolder:
    For Each cel In rngPict.Cells
        myFile = Dir(myFolder & cel.Value & "?") 'with extension in cel.value...
        If myFile <> "" Then

            myPicture = myFolder & myFile
        
        With wdApp.Selection
        
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
            .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
            .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
            .Font.Size = 12
            
            Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape
            Set wrdPic = .Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Filename:=myPicture, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
            
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 10).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 12).Text)
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Text)
            .TypeText ". "
            .TypeText (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Text)
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeParagraph
            
        End With
            
        End If
        
    Next cel

End Sub

Here are photos of my current spreadsheet, current word document produced and expected word document to be produced:




Your code does not move the cursor in Word, resulting in all the content being inserted at the beginning of the document.
Instead of using Selection, which is highly inefficient, use a Range. In the  example below Characters.Last is the range being worked with.
Sub Module2()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngPict As Range, rngP As Range, cel As Range
    Dim myDialog As FileDialog, myFolder As String, myFile As String, myPicture As String
    Dim x As Single, y As Single, W As Single, h As Single
    Const picturesColumn As String = "A" 'the column keeping the pictures name list
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, picturesColumn).End(xlUp).Row 'last row for photo names
    Set rngPict = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, picturesColumn), ws.Cells(lastR, picturesColumn)) 'the photo names range
    
    Set myDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With myDialog
        .Title = "Select the folder with structure photos"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub 'nothing has been selected...
        myFolder = .SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
    End With
    
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        
        Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
    
    End With
    
    'the following only needs to be set once
    With wdDoc.Content
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With
    
    'this only needs to be declared once - not in a loop
    Dim wrdPic As Word.InlineShape
    Dim picDesc As String
    
    'Iterate between each cell of pictures range and insert if picture exists in myFolder:
    For Each cel In rngPict.Cells
        myFile = Dir(myFolder & cel.Value & "?") 'with extension in cel.value...
        If myFile <> "" Then

            myPicture = myFolder & myFile
        
            Set wrdPic = wdDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(Filename:=myPicture, LinkToFile:=False, _
                SaveWithDocument:=True, Range:=wdDoc.Characters.Last)
            
            picDesc = vbCr & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 10).Text
            picDesc = picDesc & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Text
            picDesc = picDesc & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 12).Text
            picDesc = picDesc & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Text & ". "
            picDesc = picDesc & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Text & vbCr & vbCr
            
            wdDoc.Characters.Last.Text = picDesc
            
        End If
        
    Next cel

End Sub


Thank you very much! This seems to work well with the formatting but still has the issue of the photo description being the same for each picture.

@KyleAnderson - You need to change the cell references for the description text.

I'm still having trouble getting the photos description in word to match the correct photos.  Do you have any further guidance on how I can get the proper descriptions to go with each photo?

@KyleAnderson - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset
